# accssing funds after converting zpub to ypub

Tags: litecoin, xpub, funds

Sorry for my bad English
first of all, I'm using ltc but didn't find a litecoin forum, however, my issue apply to btc situation as well, and very new to this.

I have a wallet in electrum "Standard - p2wpkh - bip32" and converted the master key zpub key to ypub key using https://jlopp.github.io/xpub-converter/
then I created a new wallet "Watch-only" using the new converted master key "ypub ....." that i got from my original zpub, and transferred all my funds from trustwallet to a electrum watch-only ypub key wallet "MG........".
it might be the dumbest move in the university, I don't even know why I have transferred them to the converted watch-only wallet, i thought it will show on my main wallet as well since i generated the ypub using the original zpub.
I have created a new wallet using the original seed then select bip39 -> segwit (p2wpkh-p2sh) and used the default derivation path and another one with the m/0', but still the funds are not there and the address i transferred the funds too isn't accessible.

does this mean the funds is lost?